# Applying style from within an expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to apply style from within an expression?

I'd like to italicize the Name field:

```
=Fields!Text.Value & " - " & Fields!CreatedDate.Value & " " & Fields!Name.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create placeholders for each of the fields inside a single textbox.  This allows you to change the styling for each specific field. I have a post about this on my blog. http://mrthetrain.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/placeholders-2/

Comment: Even your blog post never mentions HOW to insert placeholders.

Comment: Right-click inside a textbox after it is selected for editing, not just selecting the whole textbox.  You will get an option to "Create Placeholder..."

Answer (score 2):

Textboxes contain textruns. Each textrun has its own style. You would need to edit the code to look something like this:

```
<Textbox>
 <TextRun>
  <Value>=Fields!Text.Value & " - " & Fields!CreatedDate.Value & " "</Value>
 </TextRun>
 <TextRun>
  <Value>=Fields!Name.Value</Value>
   <Style>
    <FontStyle>Italic</FontStyle>
   </Style>
 </TextRun>
</Textbox>
```